# VS Code Laravel straight underline in blade files autocomplete doesn't work

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code, laravel-blade

I have problem with autocomplete in blade files. Code like Route::, URL::, Request:: etc. is underline with straight line.

And doesn't autocomplete.
[Check request and URL code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEvh9.png)

In others PHP files autocomplete work fine and above code is not underlined. Problem is just with blade files.

[I want autocomplete like this in blade file. This is web.PHP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivSTz.png)

I have installed few extensions for Laravel and PHP.
[laravel extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGhOT.png)

Comment: please show them as text and ideally as links to their marketplace pages. it may help you to use `code --list-extensions`. see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541

Comment: i found problem but dont know solve. Problem is with this package
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper
If i install it and generate file, this is not working in blade files. In other php files is autocomplete fine.

Comment: please [edit] your post to include minimal steps to reproduce the issue.